# Is JSoup's select() method contextual?

Tags: java, jsoup

When I do:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element element = document.getElementById("body");
Element article = document.select("div[id=article]").first();
```

If the element I'm trying to query for to assign to `article` is a child of a child of `<body/>`, will it query successully?

Or would I need to navigate to whatever the parent of `article`, and then call the `select()` method on the parent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you no try it yourself first and ask question here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this?

```
 Element article = document.getElementById("article");
```

Comment: Would that work if the element <article/> is not an intermediate child of the document?

Comment: yes, this will work, from javadoc: *Find an element by ID, including or under this element.*